# Работа с изображением в php

Tags: php, изображения

Есть `gif` картинка. Нужно ее преобразовать в `png` и главное чтобы в ней изменился режим цвета (с индексированного в RGB) и так чтобы эта новая картинка `png` могла воспринимать прозрачный цвет. Помогите это реализовать на php. У меня никак не получается. Перепробовал многое...

Comment: покажите код который у вас не работает

Comment: `$path_gif="pic.gif";
$source_file = imagecreatefromgif($path_gif);
$path_png="pic.png";
imagepng($source_file, $path_png);`

Comment: По сути это чисто преобразование `gif` в `png` но так у картинки остается цветовой режим. Мне нужно ее мало того преобразовать, так еще и изменить количество цветов с 256 в 16 тыс.

Comment: После преобразования у картинки стоит цветовой режим "индексные цвета" (С помощью фотошопа посмотрел), мне нужно изменить его на режим `RGB`. Как это можно сделать с помощью `php`?

Answer (score 1):

перед функцией `imagepng` попробуйте следующее:

```
imagesavealpha($source_file);
```

Comment: Да, это помогло добавить прозрачный цвет. А можно ли вообще увеличить диапозон цветов при переводе, так чтобы это было полноценная `png` картинка?

Answer (score 0):

На сколько я понял, стандартные методы PHP плохо дружат с прозрачностью.

Comment: Ну, можно сказать, что да.